# How do you actually install ndiswrappers without internet connection?

Tags: ndiswrapper

How do you install ndiswrappers without internet connection because the link for that in the following link doesn't work:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

and I need to be able to install the driver for a Linksys AE3000 wireless network adapter to practice the lab for my wireless networking class in the class room during my instructors office hours. I tried to do this on my own, but I hit a dead end when I realized the link that explains how to do this doesn't work when I was in the class room practicing.

Comment: Doesn't work as in? What happened when you tried?

Comment: That's just it though I didn't try because I have no idea how to use the command unless it works just like any other command and the part of the guide that shows how is missing.

Comment: Also I have no man page for it, but I know I could install one for it if one exists.

Comment: Nevermind I guess becuase I just installed it using a repository as follows:

sudo apt-get install ndisgtk

Comment: However, I was asking in case I'm in the class room again on my laptop and I don't have internet connection, but I need to install something for Windows again that isn't available for Linux because I can't get a wireless signal in the classroom and I am not able or probably even allowed to connect one of the computers Ethernet cables in the classroom to my laptop.

Comment: I need to use my laptop because he wants us to open the cli or terminal and obtain the ip address for the wireless lan on either our cell phone or our labtop, but my phone won't let me issue an ifconfig for some reason or see the output and my laptop doesn't have wireless AC. However, I believe I only need up to Wireless N support though and my laptop does have that, so maybe I should be asking why my laptop Wireless Connection is not connecting to the Access Point for the lab I'm practicing.